# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:1.0.0

Tags: android, socket.io

I have a problem with a gradle when I change version of nkzawa:socket.io-client. The last version work is com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0

`ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:1.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app`

Answer (score 1):

You are having it because 0.6.0 is the last available version of this lib for android:
https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.github.nkzawa%3Asocket.io-client

Comment: ok thanks, I see this https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/blob/master/History.md#100--2017-07-14

Comment: right, but it's different one - you are using fork from original lib. So that on, what you use (nkzawa:socket.io-client) is 0.6 
In the same time, socketio:socket.io-client has version 1. 

Please, consider on using original lib if you need v 1.0 but first try to understand what fork lib brings to original functionality, maybe you need it.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 libraries to work with Socket.IO in Android

[Socket.IO-client Java](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java)

[Naoyuki Kanezawa Android Socket.IO](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/)

The latest version for the first one is **1.0.0**, to add it as a gradle dependency for Android Studio, in build.gradle.

```
compile ('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
  // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
  exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

The latest version for the second one is **0.6.0**, add it in build.gradle.

```
implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0'
```

Based on [this blog](https://medium.com/@divyeshmali236/working-with-socket-io-in-android-6a2671c1cc19), they recommend the second one, because it

- Provides easy and simple implementation
- Provides reliability, auto-reconnection support, dis-connection detection, binary, multiplex, room this all are supported.

Which library should we use? It's up to you.